# DVI to HDMI adaptor: computer recognizes adapter but no signal output

Tags: drivers, hdmi, adapter, tv, dvi

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 on quite an old computer, a Gigabyte GA-B75-D2V motherboard with Intel B75 onboard graphics. The output has VGA and DVI-D slots.

I bought a Startech DVI2HD adapter (chipset LT8522EX) to get DVI->HDMI 1080p graphics on TV. The computer recognizes the adapter and it shows up on xrandr - when I use VNC to get a remote desktop I can get 1920*1080 resolution - but the TV insists on saying "no signal". It has no problem with any of my other HDMI inputs.

One weird thing is that when I'm using GDM3, when the adapter is plugged in I can't get to the login screen, it just goes black after the Plymouth screen. (Same thing happens when dual-booting in on Windows.) But this doesn't happen when using LightDM, I can get to the login screen, though there's still no DVI->HDMI signal output.

`xrandr` output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-1 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00* 
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
HDMI-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00 +
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

(Is it weird that the adapter is recognized as HDMI rather than DVI?)

Here's a screenshot showing that Ubuntu recognizes the adapter:

[image: Ubuntu Settings-Display screen]

I've tried all the tweaks I can find online, from using different HDMI cables to looking for new drivers to trying different framerates to meddling with the BIOS, but to no avail. Do you have any ideas or should I just take it back to the shop and settle for a VGA-HDMI adapter?

Comment: How did you take that screenshot with "Single Display" there was no output out of that adapter, and single display disabling the original screen? Did you not apply the settings? It might be the case that your ancient GPU is not powerful enough to drive two displays at once, and that you need to choose between them

Comment: As I mentioned, I was using VNC to view a remote desktop on another computer. (That's usually how I access this computer as it's main job is home server.)

I tried unplugging the VGA but the DVI still isn't recognized. I'm puzzled at how Ubuntu can see it but it doesn't function at boot, even with the VGA unplugged.

Comment: Okay, I've tried it with a straight DVI-HDMI cable and it works fine, so the problem seems to be the adapter. This is annoying because the adapter included a USB sound card to add audio to the HDMI output, but I suppose I'll just have to get separate speakers.